# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function elegant_description() in header.php in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting error in my Wordpress site

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function elegant_description() in header.php

I am googling about the problem. But can't solve it.

Here is my `head` portion of `header.php` file

```
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<?php
elegant_description();
elegant_keywords();
elegant_canonical();

do_action( 'et_head_meta' );

$template_directory_uri = get_template_directory_uri();?>

<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.documentElement.className = 'js';
</script>

<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

Anybody help please ? Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using elegant theme ?

Comment: I recommend you download the latest version of your theme from the stylish theme website, and manually replace the files in your  directory.

Comment: @CHABLI....yes...I am using elegant theme. But all are ok till yesterday. From today it gives error...I didn't change anything !!

Comment: @CHABLI...but if I manually replace with the latest version all my work till now upon this theme will be gone ?

Comment: have you already update your theme ?

Comment: @CHABLI....not yet

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
The main cause of the issue was the missing files of Divi theme. There were many files missing in Divi folder. I uploaded a fresh copy of DiVi theme and the problem was solved.